# CouchBase Client Fails to Cache Object less than 20mb. Time Out Error

Tags: java, caching, couchbase

I am caching my serialized POJO s(4mb-8mb  size objects) *`concurrently`* into Couchbase server with CouchBase client (couchbase-client-1.4.3).

```
for(upto 20 itertarions){  
    new Thread().start().. //this thread cache the objects  
    Thread.sleep(500); //   the less sleep time, the more cache failures :(
}
```

I have 2 replicated servers. The client can cach small size objects, but when the object size increases, it throws exceptions.

```
Caused by: net.spy.memcached.internal.CheckedOperationTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for operation - failing node: 192.168.0.1/192.168.0.2:11210
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:167)
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:140)`
```

I found similar questions and answers. How ever, I am not a position to upgrade my memory as the applications which use the couchbase client have their concerns of memory.  How ever I tried adding JVM arguments such as `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500`

This is how I create couchBase cache client

```
CouchbaseConnectionFactoryBuilder cfb = new CouchbaseConnectionFactoryBuilder();
        cfb.setFailureMode(FailureMode.Retry);
        cfb.setMaxReconnectDelay(5000); 
        cfb.setOpTimeout(15000);
        cfb.setOpQueueMaxBlockTime(10000);
        client=new CouchbaseClient(cfb.buildCouchbaseConnection(
            uris,BUCKET_TYPE,PASSWORD));
```

I tried with maximum time gaps to make caching successful and avoid time outs.But it also doesn't work.In our real live applications, usual 7 or 8 caches can happen within a second. The applications cannot hold the process until the cache happens successfully.(it if waits, then caching is useless because of its time consumption. Getting direct Database is always cheaper!!!)

Pleas any one let me know how can improve my couchbase client(since I have limitations of hardware and JVM limitations, I am looking a way to improve the client) to avoid such time outs and improve the performance? Cannot I do serializations compressions out of the couchbase client and do it myself ?

**Updated: My COUCHBASE Setup.**
 - I am caching serialized object which has 5 to 10mb sizes.
-I have 2 nodes in difference machines.
-Each pc has 4GB RAM. CPUs are: one pc is 2 cores and other 4 cores. (Is it not enough ? )
-The client application runs in the pc which has 4 cores.
-I just configured a LAN for this testing.
-Both OS are ubuntu 14. one pc is 32 bit another one 64bit.
-The couchbase version is Latest Community Edition `couchbase-server-community_2.2.0_x86_64` .(Is this buggy? :( )
- Couchbase client `Couchbase-Java-Client-1.4.3`
- There are 100 threads starts with a 500ms gap. Each thread cache into CB.

Also, I checked the System monitoring. The PC which the CB node  and the client runs shows more CPU and RAM usage but, the other replicated PC (less hardware features) does not show much hardware usage and it is normal.

EDIT: Can this happens because of the client side issue or the CB server ? Any idea please ?

Comment: Can you give some details on your setup? How many documents are you trying to store, how many nodes in the CB cluster, how much RAM? What's the networking between the app server and cluster? At I guess I'd say one or more components of your system are under-sized, as I can easily store many hundreds of large objects per second on a relatively modest setup.

Comment: @DaveRigby. Thank you very much for your attention on my question. I updated my question as of your comments.

Comment: Hmm, not really trying to answer the question, but this scenario seems to be outside the scope of what CB might ordinarily be useful for. It still should not cause problems, just curious to know what your application might be? Perhaps plain SSD-backed storage would be a better choice?

Comment: @rmayer06 . Thanks for you comment. Sorry for delay reply(stilll struggling to come up with a solution for this.) I am not clear your statement "`but this scenario seems to be outside the scope of what CB might ordinarily be useful for.`"  Since the documentations of CB says, CB supports to cache upto 20mb size objects and high performance.Also CB site itself exhibits CB as a caching solution as well as  a better replacement for memcached.  Here my objects are just less than 10mb(less  than half sized as Doc of CB says.)

Comment: I know what the CB doc says, I'm just saying for all practical purposes, if you are storing millions of 10-mb objects in CB, you are probably going to run into issues just based on what I know about how CB works; that notwithstanding, it would be good to hear about your results. I would certainly feel better about it if your CB instance had SSD-backed storage.

Comment: @Aash have you tried to add one/few more CB servers to the cluster? I think that might resolve. Also can you please publish your java code used to store serialized objects to CB?